# Android in-app billing: always receive RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android

My Android iab app always returns RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE. I can make sure the app was running on the device, not the emulator. But my colleague's Android mobile phone can run it normally. Who can give some advice or hint? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> To test In-app Billing in an application you must install the
>   application on an Android-powered device. You cannot use the Android
>   emulator to test In-app Billing. The device you use for testing must
>   run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or later platform (API level
>   4 or higher), and have the most current version of the Google Play
>   application installed. If a device is not running the most current
>   Google Play application, your application won't be able to send In-app
>   Billing requests to Google Play. ...
>
> The following section shows you how to set up and use the In-app
>   Billing test tools.

--https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a compatible Android (1.6 and later) and Market app version (2.3.4 and later, IIRC) and that it is initialized (you have opened it at least once and accepted the license agreement).